# plm panel regression error with duplicate id/time observations

Tags: r, regression, panel, plm

I need to run a regression on a panel data. My data looks at prices of hotel room plans for two distinct observation points (a high season date and low season date).

I have [this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6nBa.png) (fyi this is a simplified data for the question, my actual dataset consists of similar types of 3855 observations of hotel prices and 15 more variables), and I run:

```
library(plm)
Y <- cbind(cost)
X <- cbind(deluxe, standard, dinner, cancell, capacity, size)
pdata <- pdata.frame(mydata, index = c("ID_roomplan", "season"), drop.index = FALSE)
fixed <- plm(Y ~ X, data = pdata, model = "within")
```

I get the following:

```
Warning message:
In pdata.frame(mydata, index = c("ID_roomplan", "season"),  :
  duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
```

I understand that this is because there needs to be a unique pair of id-time (i.e. ID_roomplan-season) for plm to work, but I do not know how to fix the data because there can be same roomplans for different prices within the same season because of differences in options (e.g. because cancellation is possible in one room type, or dinner is included in one room).

I feel that I have two options:

1. creating new ID_roomplan categories by distinguishing not just
   between the room plans also including the dummy variable options as
   identifiers, and then conducting plm.
   OR
2. do the lm regression models for high season and low season separately
   and not use plm.

Which option would be best and also are there are any other options?